# Dense subalgebras of topological algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, ring-theory, topological-groups

Let $A$ be a topological unital algebra and let $B$ be its dense subalgebra with unit. Let $I$ be a right ideal of $B$. Is the closure of $I$ a right ideal of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'yes'.

1. Let $ I $ be a right ideal of $ B $.
2. Let $ a \in A $.
3. By the denseness of $ B $ in $ A $, there exists a directed set $
       \Lambda $ and a net $ (b_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda} $ in $ A $
   that converges to $ a $.
4. Let $ y \in {\text{cl}_{A}}(I) $.
5. There exists a directed set $ I $ and a net $ (y_{i})_{i \in I} $ in
   $ I $ that converges to $ y $.
6. Observe that $ I \times \Lambda $ is a directed set equipped with
   the product partial ordering.
7. Consider the net $ (y_{i} b_{\lambda})_{(i,\lambda) \in I \times
       \Lambda} $, which is made up of elements of $ I $ because $ I $ is a
   right ideal.
8. As algebra multiplication is continuous, we see that $ \displaystyle
       ya = \lim_{(i,\lambda) \in I \times \Lambda} y_{i} b_{\lambda} \in
       {\text{cl}_{A}}(I) $.
9. Therefore, $ {\text{cl}_{A}}(I) $ is a right ideal of $ A $, by the
   arbitrariness of $ y $ and $ a $.

It is also necessary to check that $ {\text{cl}_{A}}(I) $ is a linear subspace of $ A $, but this is easy to show, using an argument with nets again.